# Can't find the volume bounded between the two cylinders.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, solid-geometry

I'm trying to find the volume bounded by:
$$x^2+z=1$$ and $$y^2+z=1$$ in the first octant.

by projection in the $xy$ plane,  my integral becomes:
$\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _{1-y^2}^{1-x^2}\:dzdydx$
which evaluates to zero, which doesn't agree with my expectations.

Comment: Should the equations be $x^2+z^2=1$,  $y^2+z^2=1$ instead if they are cylinders?

Comment: No, they are also a type of cylinders, called parabolic cylinders if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By graphing the region in three-dimensions:

[image]

we can see that the region is bounded from above by both cylinders and elsewhere by the coordinate planes, we can also notice that the region is symmetric about $y=x$.

So we set up our triple integral as follows:
$$\int _0^1\int _x^1\:\int _0^{1-y^2}\:dzdydx+\int _0^1\int _0^x\:\int _0^{1-x^2}\:dzdydx=2\int _0^1\int _0^x\:\int _0^{1-x^2}\:dzdydx$$
which evaluates to half in the end

Answer (score 1):

Note that the volume under the surfaces $x^2+z=1$ and $y^2+z=1$ in the first octant is the same. Therefore, its integral can be evaluated as

$$V = 2\int_0^1dx\int_0^xdy\int_0^{1-y^2} dz= 2\int_0^1dx\int_0^x(1-y^2)dy
= 2\int_0^1(x-\frac13 x^3)dx=\frac56$$

Comment: Since $y < x$, the upper limit for $z$ should be $1 - x^2$, otherwise you're including points above the surface $z = 1 - x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

When graphed: this region is shown to have a symmetry about the like y = x. As a result, we can proceed by simply adding that as a region boundary, and multiplying the result by 2. This allows us to take the integral of one function of z as opposed to two. The region under a surface z bounded by x and y can be given by the general form $\ \int_{R}^{}\int_{R}^{}z dy dx  $ where we take the y area of a function bounded by z and integrate that area with respect to the x area of a function bounded by z. Because we use symmetry, either of the two functions relating z would work, however they are not arbitrary as it will define the order of integration. Let's use the function $z=1-x^2$

We continue by setting up our bounds of integration:$\ \int_{R}^{}\int_{R}^{}1-x^2 dy dx  $ it is crucial that the outer integral have numerical bounds in order to end up with an numerical integral so we proceed by first using the relation y = x for the integral with respect with y (our inner integral) saving our (0,1) for our outer integral x. This yields a final integral of:

2$\ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(1-x^2) dy dx  $

The computation is as follows

2$\ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(1-x^2) dy dx  $

2$\ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}(y-yx^2) |_{y=0}^{y=x} dx  $

2$\ \int_{0}^{1}(x-\frac{x}{3}^3) dx  $

2$\  ({\frac{x}{2}}^2-{\frac{x}{12}}^4) |_{0}^{1}  $

2($\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}$)

$\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer without looking at the graph of the region, it will make the answer mush better if you can add an image of the region (for future visitors) also your answer is overly simplified, thank you after all.

Comment: @Essam The inner integral should be $\int_0^x (1 - x^2) dy = x (1 - x^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I just wrote a correct answer for my self.